# Post Photos to friends wall: Error OAuthException 240

Tags: facebook, post, photos

Post Photos to friends wall: Error **OAuthException** 240

I developed a Facebook App where in it is possible to post a photo to the wall of a friend.
I used this code:

```
FB.api("/123456789/photos", 'post', { message: textMessage, accessToken:tempAccessToken, url:imageUrl}, function(response)
```

It works for almost all my friends, only for some friends I get the error message: **“(#240) This user isn't allowed to upload photos to this object's wall”**

Blocked a privacy setting of the user to post to his/her wall?

Comment: Sounds like you were trying to post to a wall that didn't "belong" to the user.  Are you sure that the users were posting to their own walls?

Comment: The user posts a photo at the wall of his/her friend. This works, only sometimes I got the error message: "“(#240) This user isn't allowed to upload photos to this object's wall"

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this *could* be a privacy issue. Why don't you do some tests on your own account - see if you can reproduce this error.

Comment: I can reproduce this error. I got this error for 1 friend.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and it happened to really be privacy issue. See Facebook Privacy settings -> Timeline & Tagging -> Who can post on your timeline. If your friend has set "Only me" then your app won't be able to post anything on that friend's wall.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error message. 
[message] => (#240) This user isn't allowed to upload photos to this object's wall

This error occurs when your app user denies the permission "Post on your behalf" at the time of application installation.

Before posting, i just checked for the publish_stream permission. If granted, then post on wall else redirect user to login url. (display the permission popup again)

```
$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
    // code for actual posting
} else {
    header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream")) );
}
```

it works for me :)